# for loop on ssh bash to rename multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Have created set of files

test1, test2, test3

the above files are on different server name xyz.com 
If at all i need to rename the files with prefix

```
ex: test1 > old_test1
    test2 > old_test2
    test3 > old_test3
```

I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh $xyz.com -t -t /bin/bash <<EOF
cd /tmp
for i in {test*}
    do
    mv -v {i} "{i/test/old_test}"
    ls -ltr
    done
exit
```

but the output is just mv -v followed by list of files and nothing is happening (rename).

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Do not you have `rename` **Perl** command?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change your `rename-command` to the following:

```
mv -v "$i" "${i/test/old_test}";
```

I tried your problems as follow.
In my directory are the following files:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

With this command:

```
for i in $(ls); do (mv "$i" "${i/test/old_test}"); done
```

i rename all files.
My files are now:

```
old_test1
old_test2
old_test3
```

Please change your for-loop like the this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh $xyz.com -t -t /bin/bash <<EOF
cd /tmp
for i in $(ls);
   do
   mv -v "$i" "${i/test/old_test}";
   ls -ltr
   done
```

Comment: Hi @Globethrottler. If you are getting the error" cannot access" it an problems with the rights from your user. Please tried i first local on your machine. If all works you need the correct user(root) to do this on the server. The user you are connecting with has no rights to rename files on the server.

Comment: locally it works without hicups, Upon getting onto ssh normal move works but while looping its throwing various errors, I applied teh above changes it says :bad substitution , All files has 700 as permission

Comment: Are you right that you are in the right directory on your server? test it with the following command: for i in $(ls /tmp); do (echo "$i"); done . You also can remove your cd command and append "/tmp" to ls in the loop

Comment: Upon doing changes like this ssh $xyz.com -t -t /bin/bash <<EOF for i in $(ls /tmp); do ; echo ("$i); i get warning message as "  /tmp : No such file or directory"

Comment: @Globethrottler. Try to change your ssh command ssh $xyz.com -t bash <<EOF

Comment: @Globethrottler. Check your /etc/ssh/sshd_config to make sure that you don't have a chroot directory set. If you do, you will need to either create a bin directory in the chroot directory and either copy or link the necessary binaries into that directory.

Comment: tried ssh $xyz.com -t bash <<EOF the output still says " /tmp/ no such file or directory" . But if i rollback on the original thread of script  if i do ls on /tmp/ i see those test1..3 files on the ssh server

Comment: @Globethrottler. Please change your loop like this: #!/bin/bash
for i in $(ls);
   do
   mv -v "$i" "${i/test/old_test}";
   ls -ltr
   done

Comment: Files still not renamed, still listing old names with the above loop change. Not sure whats happening. (The mv command is not taking the input from for command but when the next line says ls -ltr it will display the file

Comment: Fixed atlast here is what i did First one : ssh xyz.com 'bash' <<'ENDSSH' second change was : for i in *test* rest remained unchanged. Many thanks for your input

Comment: The construct `for i in $(ls)` is the [VERY FIRST ENTRY](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) on the bash pitfalls list. Variables within heretext are expanded on the local side, not the remote side.

Answer (score 0):

## !/bin/bash

ssh $xyz.com 'bash' <<'ENDSSH'
cd /tmp
for i in {test*}
do
mv "${i}" "${i/test/old_test}";
ls -ltr
done
exit